# What's a valid left-hand-side expression in JavaScript grammar?

Tags: javascript, grammar, ecma262

Okay, we all **know** what the valid left-hand-side expressions are. Kind of.*

But, looking at the definition from [the ECMA-Script standard](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2), I'm very confused:

```
LeftHandSideExpression :
    NewExpression
    CallExpression
```

Is that just an error in the definition, or am I getting something wrong here? I mean, doesn't that actually mean that

```
new Object = 1; // NewExpression AssignmentOperator PrimaryExpression
function () { return foo; }() = 1;// CallExpression AssignmentOperator PrimaryExpression
```

are supposed to be valid assignment expressions?

---

<sub>* From my humble understanding, this would make much more sense:</sub>

```
LeftHandSideExpression :
    Identifier
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    MemberExpression . IdentifierName
    CallExpression [ Expression ]
    CallExpression . IdentifierName
```

Comment: Your second example will work if you wrap the function call in brackets: `(function () { return window; }()).x = 1`

Comment: @Daniel: Right, I updated the example

Comment: @user123444555621 Your (humble understanding) definition of `LeftHandSideExpression` is missing the grouping operator `( LeftHandSideExpression )`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To concisely answer your question, everything beneath the `LeftHandSideExpression` production is a valid `LeftHandSideExpression`.

---

I think the question you are really asking is:

> What is a valid `LeftHandSideExpression` and also assignable?

The answer to that is anything that resolves to a `Reference` which is a well defined concept in the specification. In your example

```
new Object = 1;
```

The `new Object` is a valid `LeftHandSideExpression` but it does not resolve to a `Reference`.

```
(new Object).x = 1;
```

The left hand side is a `MemberExpression . IdentifierName` which according to the spec the final step is:

> Return a value of type Reference **...**

---

If you consider it 2 separate properties it makes a lot more sense.

1. Is it a valid LeftHandSideExpression?
2. Is it a valid reference?

Property 1 is determined in the syntactical analysis phase and property 2 is determined in the semantic analysis phase. Check out **8.7.2 PutValue (V, W)** for more details.

Here is a full explanation in the specification itself:

**8.7 The Reference Specification Type**

The Reference type is used to explain the behaviour of such operators as delete, typeof, and the assignment operators. For example, the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference. The behaviour of assignment could, instead, be explained entirely in terms of a case analysis on the syntactic form of the left-hand operand of an assignment operator, but for one difficulty: function calls are permitted to return references. This possibility is admitted purely for the sake of host objects. No built-in ECMAScript function defined by this specification returns a reference and there is no provision for a user-defined function to return a reference. (Another reason not to use a syntactic case analysis is that it would be lengthy and awkward, affecting many parts of the specification.)

---

After taking a look at your suggestion I believe it would throw off certain valid expressions *(Note: I don't condone this.)*

```
function OuterObj() {
    this.Name = "Outer";
    this.InnerObj = function() {
        this.Name = "Inner";
    }
}

var obj; (obj = new new OuterObj().InnerObj).Name = "Assigned";
```

This is a case where `NewExpression` is important

Comment: True. I always thought that phase 2 is carried out at run-time while phase 1 occurs at parse-time. Thus, `if (false) { new Object = 1; }` should not be a syntax error, and does ideed work in Safari. A look at the Firefox source code led me to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=509098#c11): Firefox treats this one as a special case. (Fun fact: error code is called `JSMSG_BAD_LEFTSIDE_OF_ASS`)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - I think doing it this way really makes sense in a dynamic language.

Comment: Why the specification setted the production ClassHeritage as "extends" LeftHandSideExpression? shouldn't it be BindingIdentifier? I found this awfully complicated. Imagine a class definition like class X extends (new Y), or class X extends (function() {})! Who in the world would need such funcionality? In fact the firefox even acused the first case as invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative JavaScript grammar which only will match valid LeftHandSideExpressions, that is, LeftHandSideExpressions that are actually assignable.

```
NewExpression :
    PrimaryExpression
    new NewExpressionQualifier Arguments
    new NewExpressionQualifier

NewExpressionQualifier :
    NewExpressionQualifier Qualifier
    NewExpression

CallExpression :
    NewExpression
    CallExpressionQualifier Arguments

CallExpressionQualifier :
    CallExpression
    CallExpressionQualifier Qualifier

LeftHandSideExpression :
    LeftHandSideExpression Qualifier
    CallExpression Qualifier
    Identifier
    ( LeftHandSideExpression )
    ( Expression , LeftHandSideExpression )

Qualifier :
    . IdentifierName
    [ Expression ]
```

Each Arguments for which the choice of associated new or call expression is ambiguous shall be associated with the nearest possible new expression that would otherwise have no corresponding Arguments. I think this is one of the reasons why there is both a NewExpression and a MemberExpression nonterminal in the JavaScript grammar.

Comment: From your definition of `LeftHandSideExpression` I conclude that `(a = 1, b)` would be an assignable `LeftHandSideExpression`. However, using it in an assignment `(a = 1, b) = 2` results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Comment: The comma operator is not a left hand side expression, since it does not return a reference (4. Return GetValue(rref)). However, it may contain a simple assignment expression as right operand. `a = 1, b = 2` may be grouped as `(a = 1) , (b = 2)`, but `(a = 1, b) = 2` would result in `GetValue(b) = 2`.