# Javascript console says: Invalid left-side assignment?

Tags: javascript

So, this is to make a secure login. i run this through chrome's javascript console and i get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment '?! please help!

```
function logIn() {
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
        for(var ret = 0, i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        ret = (31 * ret + this.charCodeAt(i)) << 0;
    }
        return ret;
    };

var user = document.getElementById("username"),
    pass = document.getElementById("password");
if ((user = "Fedora") && (pass.hashCode() = -976887139)) {
    window.alert("Captain Fedora: SuperUser");

}
}
```

Comment: A cleaver trick to avoid making this make is called Yoda conditions, train yourself to write if statements like this: `if("Fedora" == user) {`, that way if you forget the second equals you will get an exception as technically assignments in if statements are valid JavaScript.

Comment: Run your code through a validator like http://jshint.com/ to help in your basic debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((user = "Fedora") && (pass.hashCode() = -976887139))
```

should be

```
if ((user == "Fedora") && (pass.hashCode() == -976887139))
```

so you do comparison, and not assignment

Comment: It's even acceptable to comparise using `===` which means comparise with type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pass.hashCode() = -976887139` is an [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators). And since the function call doesn't [return a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13124417/1048572), it's invalid to assign to it. You probably wanted the [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

```
pass.hashCode() == -976887139
```

Also, you will want to get the [`value`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties) of those DOM elements (I can't believe the password input *has* a `hashCode` method at all), and you also want to compare the content of the `user` variable with that string instead of assigning them.

```
var user = document.getElementById("username").value,
    pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
if (user == "Fedora" && pass.hashCode() == -976887139) {
    window.alert("Captain Fedora: SuperUser");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((user = "Fedora") && (pass.hashCode() = -976887139))
```

change to

```
if ((user == "Fedora") && (pass.hashCode() == -976887139))
```

also 'reuturn ret' may return undefined because in wrong scope. var ret = 0 only work in 'for' scope