# Can a function's return value be an lvalue in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jscript, lvalue

Microsoft allows to set environment variables in JScript with the following syntax:

```
var sh = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");
var env = sh.Environment("PROCESS");
env("TEST") = "testvalue";
```

I wonder about the third line - and with me JSLint, which calls this line a "Bad Assigment".

But it works!

Is it ECMAscript standard compatible to have a function's return value as an lvalue (like here)?

If yes: How would one write such a function?

Comment: Cool! Please make that snippet (together with a link to the official docs) an answer to my [*Real world examples of a function returing a reference* question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124417/real-world-examples-of-ecmascript-functions-returning-a-reference)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the standard permits functions to returns references. No, you cannot write such a function in Javascript. ;)

> <...> the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference. <...> function calls are permitted to return references. This possibility is admitted purely for the sake of host objects. No built-in ECMAScript function defined by this specification returns a reference and there is no provision for a user-defined function to return a reference. http://es5.github.io/#x8.7

Comment: but what you can do is setting properties of the Object, the returned reference points to `ret("sth").someProp = "sth"`

Comment: This was quick and exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: this doesn't mean `ret()` returns a reference. Reference is a pair `[base,prop]` and the function only evaluates the base part.

Comment: @thg435 Yes, what i meant was sth like `var someObjs = [{a:"",someProp:"b"}]; (function (a) {return someObjs[a]})(0).someProp = "c";console.log(someObjs[0].someProp) //c`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: Still, your IEFE there returns the `{a:"",someProp:"b"}` object on which then a property is set, it does not return a reference.