# jquery "return false" not working properly inside update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jquery to validate a text box placed within update Panel

```
$("[id*='btnCreate']").live('click', function () 
{
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
  if (!regex.test($("[id*='txtbxTemplateName']").val())) 
  {
     alert('hit');

     $("[id*='lblError']").text() = 'Template name is invalid!';

     return false;
  }
});
```

the click event function is being called, but after returning false it is still hitting the code behind.

Please help me on this.

Comment: This `$("[id*='lblError']").text() = 'Template name is invalid!'` is not right...

Comment: What loop? What code behind?

Comment: also make sure to rebind your event again when you are using Update Panel    [code]
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    // re-bind your jQuery events here
});[/code]

Comment: @Bergi "if block" "running the default action and sending a request to the server"

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean by "still hitting the code behind" that the default action of the button is not being prevented. This is because the code never gets to `return false` because of an error:

```
$("[id*='lblError']").text() = 'Template name is invalid!';
return false;
```

should be

```
$("[id*='lblError']").text('Template name is invalid!');
return false;
```

You have just exposed, however, why `return false` is a bad way to prevent the default action of an event. It is bad because any errors in the error handler will mean that the default action is not prevented, because `return false` is the last statement in the handler.

If you use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), all kinds of beautiful things will happen. Chief among them is that you can place the statement earlier in the handler:

```
$("[id*='btnCreate']").live('click', function (event) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
  if (!regex.test($("[id*='txtbxTemplateName']").val())) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hit');
    $("[id*='lblError']").text('Template name is invalid!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Well [actually it's not a syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13124417/1048572) but just a type error :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Updated just for you.