# Is all javascript object reference type?

Tags: javascript

All, Say we have the code like below.

```
var b ={};

var a=b;
b=null;
if (a==null)
{
    alert('a is null');
}
```

Before the code running, I had thought the `a` should be null, because I thought `a` and `b` are pointing to same object or they are supposed to be the same address. but it is not . Isn't javascript object reference type like classical language (c++/c#/java)? Or did I miss something important? Thanks.

Comment: it is like java, yes. `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object, when `b` does now point to `null`, then `a` still points to the object.

Comment: `b` contained a reference to the same object as `a`. Then you modified it `b` to contain a value of `null` instead, but `a` still points at the original object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, all variables are held -- and passed -- by value.

However, in the case of objects (anything not a primitive) that value is a reference.

```
var v1, v2;
v1 = {
  someProp: true
}; // Creates an object

v2 = v1; // The object now has two references pointed to it.
v1 = null; // The object now has one reference.
console.log(v2); // See the value of the object.
v2 = null; // No references left to the object. It can now be garbage collected.
```

Answer (score 3):

No. In fact, there are no "reference" types in JavaScript<sup>1</sup> and there is definitely *not* Reference semantics for variables. There are two classes of values: Primitives, and Objects. However, this question/problem doesn't deal with the distinction.

Rather the question is due to not understanding variable assignment:

```
// let X be a singleton object, {}
var b = X;    // the object X is assigned to the variable `b`
              // (this does NOT make a copy)
              // b -> X
var a=b;      // the object that results from evaluating `b` is assigned to `a`
              // however, `a` and `b` are SEPARATE non-related variables
              // (once again, no copies are made)
              // b -> X, a -> X
b=null;       // assigns the value null to `b` - this does NOT AFFECT `a`
              // b -> null, a -> X
b==null       // true, as b -> null
a==null       // false, as a -> X
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There are mutable objects, and then there is the Reference Specification Type; the RST does not directly apply to the question and it is *not* related to "reference" types, but it is used to describe l-value behavior of an assignment.

While implementations may use "references" or "pointers" internally, the semantics are entirely defined merely by accepting that *an object is itself* and that neither an assignment nor use in an expression (such as a function argument) create a copy.

Comment: +1. Some more background: [How to explain object references in ECMAScript terms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23554770/1048572)

Comment: Well, there is a [*reference specification type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way in any language I know. JavaScript still uses references to objects, just not to variables.

Assignment changes what the variable contains. When you do `b=null;`, you don't change the object, you change `b`. Since `a` hasn't changed, it still contains the old reference to the original object.

If you did, say:

```
var b = {};
var a = b;
b.foo = "bar";
if (a.foo === "bar")
{
    alert("foobar");
}
```

Then the `alert` would indeed run.

Answer (score 1):

The reason a is not null is because you are assigning it to the value of b BEFORE setting b to null.  In Javascript, the variable saves whatever the right hand side is evaluated to when it was assigned.  Therefore, if you wanted a to be null, you would do it like this:

```
var b = {};
b = null;
var a = b;

alert(a) // outputs null
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more - **Self Ref - Cyclic Ref in JS**

```
var x = {name:'myName'}
var y=x
x['y'] = y
```

Object {name: "myName", y: Object}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi said, It is like java or C#!

I tested it in the C#.

```
                TestClass b = new TestClass();
                TestClass a = b;
                b = null;//doesn't change the object , 
//only change the variable b. the object is remained.
                if (a == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a is null");//not hit here
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Thanks you all. It really makes me understand it better.