# Node.js What is object Cloning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

i want to know why we have to clone the objects instead of direct assigning.

```
 var obj1 = {x: 5, y:5};
 var obj2 = obj1;
 obj2.x = 6;
 console.log(obj1.x); // logs 6
```

i already got the solution but i want to know Why the obj2 working 
like a reference variable ?

Comment: Because that's how JS works.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554770/how-to-explain-object-references-in-ecmascript-terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what this code does step by step:

#### 1 -

```
var obj1 = {x: 5, y:5};
```

Create an object `{x: 5, y:5}` and store its reference in variable `obj1`

#### 2 -

```
var obj2 = obj1;
```

Create variable `obj2` and attribute the value of `obj1` to it. As the value of `obj1` is a reference to an object, then `obj2` will now be pointing to the same object.

#### 3 -

```
obj2.x = 6;
```

Change the value of the property `x` in the object being referenced

#### 4 -

```
console.log(obj1.x); // logs 6
```

Print `x` property from the object being referenced by `obj1`. As `obj1` and `obj2` are pointing at the same place, the output is `6`.

---

This is the same behavior that any language that works with references to objects will have. Java, C, C++, C#, etc. In OOP languages you normally have a `clone()` method that will do a field by field copy. But in the case of JS, such method doesn't exist, you need to do a deep copy of every element. You can find a nice set of answers regarding how to clone elements in JS here: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)