# Are import values disconnected from their export values still read-only?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Given is the following module structure:

```
// module A:
export let a = 1; // named export
export function inc() { a++; } // named export

// module B:
let b = 1;
export default b; // default export (equivalent to `export default 1`)
export function inc() { b++; } // named export

// module C:
let c = {};
export default c; // default export

// module E:
import a, {inc as incA} from "./A";
import b, {inc as incB} from "./B";
import c from "./C";

incA();
console.log(a); // logs 2, because "a" has a live connection to the export value
a++; // Error (because a is a live read-only view on the export)

incB();
console.log(b); // logs 1, because "b" is disconnected from the export value
b++; // Does this throw an error as well?

c.prop = true; // I think mutations are always allowed, right?
c = {}; // but are reassignment allowed too?
```

If I have a default export of an expression (`export default b` or `export default 1`) a corresponding import is disconnected from this export value. Considering this, is such an import still read-only that is, can I reassign `a` or `c`?

Comment: Can't you just run the code and see the results?

Comment: You can try to run the code with `node --harmony`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import bindings are always read-only, see the abstract [`CreateImportBinding`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-createimportbinding) operation in the spec, step 5:

> 5. Create an **immutable** indirect binding in *envRec* for *N* that references *M* and *N2* as its target binding and record that the binding is initialized.

*(my emphasis)*

That operation is used by [`ModuleDeclarationInstantiation`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-moduledeclarationinstantiation) when processing the import entries of the module.

So:

> ```
> b++; // Does this throw an error as well?
> ```

Yes, `b` is read-only.

> ```
> c.prop = true; // I think mutations are always allowed, right?
> ```

Provided the exported object allows it, yes.

> ```
> c = {}; // but are reassignment allowed too?
> ```

No, `c` is read-only.

---

In a comment, you've said:

> but when there isn't a live-binding anymore, it makes no sense to make such variables read-only

It's useful to remember that they aren't *variables,* they're *bindings*. While variables are one kind of binding, not all bindings are variables (even in ES5 and earlier).

Regarding them being read-only when it doesn't matter, remember that there are two layers of bindings involved:

1. The live binding of the *export* in the source module.
2. The live binding of the *import* in the consuming module.

In order to make #2 writable when the value from #1 isn't going to change, the import mechanism would have to know that, but that information isn't in [the module's exports](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects). The exports just give the name of the exported binding.

Moreover, having mutable import bindings as well as immutable import bindings is more complicated to understand and more complicated to implement. (Reassigning imported bindings is also, from a style perspective, confusing.)

It's also important to remember that the fact they're live bindings means the value of an import *may change*. Assume:

`mod1.js`:

```
export let foo = 41;
export function incrementFoo() {
    ++foo;
};
```

`mod2.js`:

```
import { foo, incrementFoo } from "./mod1.js";
console.log(foo); // 41
incrementFoo();
console.log(foo); // 42 <== it changed
```

In that particular case, it was code in `mod2.js` that caused the change (by calling `incrementFoo`), but it doesn't have to be. It could be because some time-related event happened in `mod1.js` to make the value change, or the result of a call by some other module into `mod1.js`, etc.

But because `mod2.js`'s `foo` is a live binding to `mod1.js`'s `foo`, `mod2.js` sees the change.

Comment: Hm, but when there isn't a live-binding anymore, it makes no sense to make such variables read-only.

Comment: @LUH3417: They aren't variables, they're bindings. (Variables are *one kind* of binding, but not all bindings are variables.) I can't speak for why the committee decided to make all import bindings immutable, but it's definitely simpler (simpler to understand, simpler to implement), and also exposes less of the internals of the module. If you want a variable, just create one `let b2 = b; b2++;`

Comment: You're right, I just try to grasp the concept in-depth. Thanks!

Comment: I've looked into the subject more closely. We're talking indeed about exported name bindings and not variables. A given name binding can only change when its lexical identifier is modified dynamically (which isn't possible), its lexical scope changes dynamically (which isn't possible either) or recursion takes place. From this point of view it makes perfect sense that imports of exported name bindings are always read-only.

Comment: Here is a [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39304668/6445533)