# ES6 variable import by reference or copy

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Suppose i have a `var.js`

```
export let x = 1;
export const f = () => x = 5;
```

Then i execute this in another file

```
import { x, f } from './var.js';
console.log(x); // 1
f();
console.log(x); // 5
```

Why is the imported variable `x` able to change accordingly?

Does `import { x }` gets re-evaluated when `x` in `var.js` changes?

Or is `x` a reference to the original `x` in `var.js` rather than a copy?

Comment: Also check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let

Comment: `export const x;` looks invalid to me.

Comment: ES2015 modules export (live) bindings, not values. Read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39259729) about the differences between bindings and references.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ES6 import/exports are actually bindings (references). As the value of `x` in original file `var.js` changes, it's reflected in another file too.

Reference: http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html

Comment: FWIW, the term "binding" is used to for every variable/parameter, etc . It's not only used for imports.

Comment: Thanks for info, willing to extend a bit on where it's used?

Comment: Any entry in an environment (scope) is a binding: https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-environment-records

Comment: Seems like it only works if you do `export let x`, but not `export default x`?

Comment: I am not aware of the difference between this two in terms of your problem. May you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

solution doesn't work for functions

```
export let e = () => {
  console.log('b')
}

window.b = () => {
  e = () => {
    console.log('c')
  }
}
```

the when calling from another file, the "reference" doesn't change.

```
import { e } from './test'
e() // b
b()
e() // still b
```