# How to import a live let variable set to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a UI library for (P)React. Repo can be viewed [here](https://github.com/secretlifeof/juhuui).

A setup function is called to initiate createElement/forwardRef functions. These are set to let variables so they can be accessed inside other files. This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937494/es6-variable-import-by-reference-or-copy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let). Variables are live views, but why are variables with functions not live views?

```js
// setup.ts
let forwardRef
let createElement

function setup(createElementIn, { forwardRef : fw }) {
  forwardRef = fw
  createElement = createElementIn
}
```

In another function it is imported like this

```js
// box.ts
import { forwardRef, createElement } from './setup'

// this works
function Box(props, ref){
  console.log('forwardRef', forwardRef) // correct function

  return createElement('div', { ...props, ...(ref && ref) })
}

// this does not work because forwardRef is undefined
export forwardRef ? forwardRef(Box) : Box
```

Box is called like this

```js
import { useRef, createElement, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { Box, setup } from 'juhuui'

// this is called only once
setup(createElement, { forwardRef })

function Hello () {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  return (<Box ref={myRef}>Hello</Box>)
}
```

Can you please tell me how my code can be restructured to work?

Comment: Can you provide an actual minimum reproducible example in the question? You use `forwardRef` as a function but there's no indication if it is actually a function and if it remains one throughout the code (since it is a mutable export).

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I added a minimal setup in the last code example. The missing part was showing how the setup function works.

Comment: Well you've got yourself in a bit of a bind here. You import `box.ts` and `setup.ts` at the same time meaning `forwardRef` will be undefined when you hit the export part. If you could (somehow) import `setup.ts` first. Do `setup(...)` and then import `box.ts` you might have more success, but this does look very messy. Perhaps you could instead have `setup.ts` run the setup code on import and only import that file, if that is an option

Comment: Yes it feels quite messy. Even if **setup.ts** and **box.ts** are imported in different files, the result is sadly the same. I have also tried a setup function that returns `{ box: forwardRef && box }` and `export const box = setup.box` with the same result.