# YDKJS up & going non-primitive equality

Tags: javascript, equality

Can somebody please explain the following passage from YDKJS Up & Going to me like I am five:

> You should take special note of the == and === comparison rules if
> you're comparing two non-primitive values, like objects (including
> function and array). Because those values are actually held by
> reference, both == and === comparisons will simply check whether the
> references match, not anything about the underlying values. For
> example, arrays are by default coerced to strings by simply joining
> all the values with commas (,) in between. You might think that two
> arrays with the same contents would be == equal, but they're not:
>
> ```
> var a = [1,2,3];
> var b = [1,2,3];
> var c = "1,2,3";
> a == c;       // true
> b == c;       // true
> a == b;       // false
> ```

What is meant by "references"? Does this mean where the array is held in memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to explain object references in ECMAScript terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23554770/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well yeah,
you see when you create array named 'arr' for example.
your memory look like this:
[image: stack heap array example]

so reference comparison actually check if the array reference point the **same** array in the heap.
stack is for value types and references.

Comment: With  that being said,  is it impossible for  a non-primitive  data-type to  have  true equality when compared to another non-primitive?