# In the ECMAScript 2022 spec (section 7.2.13) what does "Object value" pertain to?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

In the section for SameValueNonNumeric [7.2.13](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric) in the final step that reads as follows:

> 7. If x and y are the same Object value, return true. Otherwise, return false.

What is `Object value` being interpreted as? From my experience I assume it means the object reference?

Comment: Yes. The value of an object is its reference.

Comment: Got it, thanks :)

Comment: Related: [How to explain object references in ECMAScript terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23554770/1048572)