# What part of ECMAScript spec mandates that String type is immutable?

Tags: javascript, language-specifications

I know that String primitive type in Javascript is immutable, via practice and word of mouth. But what combination of rules in the ECMA-262 makes it so? More specifically, why the second line in the following example silently does nothing?

```js
const str = 'abc';
str[1] = '8';
console.log(str); // prints unmodified "abc", not "a8c".
```

[Section 6.1.4](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) describes the internal composition of String datum. It does not contain anything about modifying the data, or at least I couldn't find anything after reading it thrice.

[Section 13.15.2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) describes the semantics of assignment. It does not contain any exceptions for any specific data type.

[Section 13.3.2.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) describes the semantics of the property accessor operator. It does not contain any exceptions for any specific data type.

So, how exactly the string data type is defined to be immutable in Javascript?

Comment: As usual, use strict mode and it's no longer silent.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for the great pointer! Indeed I see "cannot assign to read only property '1' of string 'abc'" when running under Node.js. -_- Also, the top element in the stack trace is `at Object.<anonymous>` - does this mean that at the moment of calling the property access operator the string primitive is already being boxed into a `String` object with all properties being read-only?

Comment: Yes, when attempting to assign a property the target is always boxed - in [`PutValue`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-putvalue) step 5, "*Let `baseObj` be ? ToObject(`V`.[[Base]])*" (which is called from the assignment operator that you linked).

Comment: Specifically, it's boxed into a "String Exotic Object".

Comment: The ECMAScript specification authors don't care that regular JavaScript developers don't understand it. When I filed an issue on the TC39 Github, they made no acknowledgment of the problem, manipulatively weaponized "community standards", took no corrective action, blamed me, and locked the issue. The issue is linked from the description in my YouTube video (which they cannot delete). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4HuAW4G9Uw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EMCAScript specification is silent about this, just as it is [silent on object identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556036/1048572) (i.e. object mutability). So yes, it's more about "*via practice and word of mouth*", but I guess a conforming implementation *could* change the memory representation of a string in the background (or even provide an API to do so as an extension).

However, you can infer the immutability of strings from the phrasing of [§6.1.4 "*The String Type*"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) that you linked:

> The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 elements.

This is a very mathematical definition, and in mathematics, *values* are always immutable. In addition, we can observe that there simply is no operation within ECMAScript that would mutate such a value.

The definition applies only to primitive values though, not to `String` objects which wrap such a value and can have additional (mutable) properties. Again, there just is no operation that would change the *[[StringData]]* internal slot of [a `String` instance](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-string-instances). This is even explicitly described in the [section on *String Exotic Objects*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-exotic-objects):

> A String object is an exotic object that encapsulates a String value and exposes virtual integer-indexed data properties corresponding to the individual code unit elements of the String value. String exotic objects always have a data property named `"length"` whose value is the number of code unit elements in the encapsulated String value. Both the code unit data properties and the `"length"` property are non-writable and non-configurable.

This is also what you observe in your example code. The assignment `str[1] = …` goes to [String's *[[DefineOwnProperty]]* internal method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-exotic-objects-defineownproperty-p-desc), which finds that [the `1` property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-exotic-objects-defineownproperty-p-desc) is non-writable, rejecting a change. The [*PutValue* abstract operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-putvalue) will then throw an exception in strict mode (or ignore the failure in sloppy mode).

Answer (score 1):

10.4.3 String Exotic Objects says: The integer-indexed data properties that correspond 1:1 to each character of the string (the string's "code unit elements") have `[[Writable]]:false`.

In non-strict mode, assignment to data properties with attribute `{ [[Writable]]: false }` fails silently (See "Ex 1: Non-strict").

However, in strict mode, simple assignment where the LeftHandSideExpression references a data property with the attribute value `{ [[Writable]]: false }` throws a TypeError. (See Appendix C "The Strict Mode of ECMAScript"). (See "Ex 2: Strict");

**"Ex 1: Non-strict:"**

```
(function(){
  'f'[0] = 1;
})();
```

**"Ex 2: Strict:"**

```
(function(){ 
  'use strict';
  'f'[0] = 1; // TypeError.
})();
```

From discussion: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:groupPost:7039829-7011351896053456897?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28groupPost%3A7039829-7011351896053456897%2C7011363968413831171%29&replyUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28groupPost%3A7039829-7011351896053456897%2C7011742156822380544%29

YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lR7BLWcqa8

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think my original answer was so wrong that it may not be redeemable at all, but since there's a great reply, I don't want to delete it outright. I will attempt to fix it.

I was *trying* to say that on the left side of an assignment there are only two choices for `[ ]`, object access by key, and destructuring. Strings are objects without keys for each index in the text value. A destructuring expression doesn't fit either, and even then it would be a new expression (value) of `undefined`, and thus not modify the original string. This may be why there is no error but it appears to do nothing. It modifies a (temporary) value of an expression that isn't stored anywhere.

Section [10.4.3.5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-stringgetownproperty) of the standard might be the closest thing to identifying the rule, saying the result is `[[Writable]]: false`, but since it is still an expression, it represents a value that can still be assigned to something, even though that value will be discarded if not.

Interestingly, `let B = 'abc'[1] = 'B'` would assign 'B' to B as expected, but not modify the string, regardless of whether it was a string constant or variable. And so `let A='abc'; let B = A[1] = 'B'` has the same effect. So again, because it is a basic type without keys for `[1]` in this case, the new expression is more of a new value than targeting the original memory where the string is stored.

Even more interesting: `let B = undefined = 'B'` *does* successfully assign 'B' to B. I'm not quite sure how, but I think it's the same case as `{}[1]` even though `undefined` is an actual value that could have been assigned to B. I think this means there's an exception for an intermediate value in a sequence of assignments if it evaluates to `undefined`, and does not pass on the `undefined` to the next expression on the left.

I think it's the same case as `undefined = 'B'` not doing anything, but that *value* on the left-hand side is still `'B'`, if assigned somewhere. I can predict that calling `func(undefined = 3)` will in fact pass a 3 to the function.

---

Original answer: It was just so dead wrong that I've removed it now. Thanks to @hijarian for waking me up with his comment about the `[ ]` operator.

Comment: Well, [13.3.2.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) explains exactly what happens on evaluating the `[ ]` operator, and at a step 2 there's a call to `GetValue` abstract operation which in case of strings will proceed to its step 4a where it'll call ToObject abstract operation. Boxing is inevitable here.

Reading individual characters in a string using the square bracket operator is an absolutely common thing, and it works as expected, no ambiguity with an array access.

Comment: @hijarian My answer was written quicky, I will seek to fix that above. Yes reading by index is common and described in the standard, but writing is not (and the key point of this question). I think reading characters by index is documented in [10.4.3.5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-stringgetownproperty) and that section might be the closest thing to identifying the rule, saying the result is `[[Writable]]: false`.

Comment: Further to this: `let A = 'abc'; let B = A[1] = 'B';` ... I believe the second statement is equivalent to: `let B = {}[2] = 'B'` which stores the 'B' only as an expression result so that it can be assigned to B. If it is not used, it is discarded, because A[1] is not writable by 10.4.3.5.

Comment: The global property `undefined` is also ReadOnly (`{ [[Writable]]: false } `)in EcmaScript 5.1+. Any attempt to assign a value to it also results in `TypeError`.  https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.1.1