# ECMAScript specification of primitives and objects

Tags: javascript

When reading through the ECMAScript specification, I noticed, it actually never mentions concepts like "pass by value" or "pass by reference".

When looking at the assignment operator, [this](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) is how it is specified:

An expression like

```
let a = 4
```

would lead to path 1.d. Which basically just sets the value of 4 to a. But same would be true for the assignment of an object.

Does this mean, it would be a conforming ECMAScript implementation to copy objects by value (which obviously isn't the case in any known implementation)?

I have checked Emacs documentation but I did not get a satisfying solution, I want an experienced JavaScrip

Comment: It's the other way around. The specification never says copies are made, so assignments are always references to the same object. See the specification of [`GetValue()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554770/how-to-explain-object-references-in-ecmascript-terms