# Unexpected reference giving from a getter method

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, getter, defineproperty

Here's an object
containing a list of strings(`valuesDictionnary`),
these strings are made readable from the outside 
of the object with a list of getters set as a 
property of the object(`gettersDictionnary`).

This strange structure is used to make the strings of the
list unconfigurable from the outside but configurable and so removable from the 
inside.

```
var obj = new (function () {

    var gettersDictionnary = {},
        valuesDictionnary = {
            anyValue: "problem"
        };

    Object.defineProperty(this, "gettersDictionnary", {
        configurable: false,
        get: function () {
            return gettersDictionnary;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(gettersDictionnary, "anyValue", {
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            return valuesDictionnary["anyValue"];
        }
    });

})();
```

Here's the point,
when a "delete" instruction is sent to one of the getters("anyValue")
from the outside of the object, it should ends up with the destruction
of the string contained in the list given by the "return" operator, not
with the destruction of the string contained in the variable `gettersDictionnary`.
But it does.

Then I'm asking why in this case the "return" operator seems to give 
a reference to the variable `gettersDictionnary`, but not its value as it
it should do.

```
console.log(obj.gettersDictionnary.anyValue); //"problem"

delete obj.gettersDictionnary.anyValue;

console.log(obj.gettersDictionnary.anyValue); //"undefined"
```

the last `console.log` should give "problem", why it doesn't ?

Here's the full code snippet :

```js
var obj = new (function () {
    
    var gettersDictionnary = {},
        valuesDictionnary = {
            anyValue: "problem"
        };
    
    Object.defineProperty(this, "gettersDictionnary", {
        configurable: false,
        get: function () {
            return gettersDictionnary;
        }
    });
    
    Object.defineProperty(gettersDictionnary, "anyValue", {
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            return valuesDictionnary["anyValue"];
        }
    });
    
})();

console.log(obj.gettersDictionnary.anyValue); //"problem"

delete obj.gettersDictionnary.anyValue;

console.log(obj.gettersDictionnary.anyValue); //"undefined"
```

Comment: Please [never use `new function(){…}`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)!

Comment: You [cannot `return` a reference to a property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13124417/1048572), sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the semantics of the `delete` operator, from the Ecmascript Spec:

> When the [[Delete]] internal method of O is called with property name
>   P and the Boolean flag Throw, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *desc* be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of *O* with property name *P*.
> 2. If *desc* is **undefined**, then return **true**.
> 3. If *desc*.[[Configurable]] is **true**, then
>
>    1. Remove the own property with name *P* from *O*.
>    2. Return **true**.
> 4. Else if *Throw*, then throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 5. Return **false**.

As you can see, the solution is make the property not `configurable`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I might not have explained my problem clearly : this property cannot be set configurable because it must be removable with the operator `delete` for some reasons, but only from the inside of the object block. Therefore I have made the variable "getterDictionnary" with a read-only access thanks to the property attached to the object "obj" that should only give the value of the variable . Then, the expected result is that the delete operator apply to a copy of the "getterDictionnary" variable and then don't remove the "anyValue" property.  But it doesn't work.