# javascript variable swapping using arrays

Tags: javascript

```
 [a,b] = [b,a]
```

How does the above code swap a and b ?

I could see that the Right hand side of the expression crates an array, but I could not understand how it can be assigned to the left hand side.

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sethunath/MqWKH/

Update : Works only in firefox !

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow this kind of pattern matching.

Comment: This would be valid syntax in CoffeeScript, which turns this into: `var _ref = [b, a], a = _ref[0], b = _ref[1];`

Comment: Pls see http://jsfiddle.net/sethunath/MqWKH/

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709866/whats-a-valid-left-hand-side-expression-in-javascript-grammar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript 1.7 adds [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29), which you're observing there. JavaScript 1.7 is supported by few browsers. Notably, however, it is supported by Mozilla Firefox when the `script` tag has a `type` attribute of `application/javascript;version=1.7`.

Comment: Maybe @Sethunath is just asking for an explanation of how it works. MDN has an article here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29

Answer (score 0):

The above code doesn't swap `a` and `b`, it will give you an

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

What do you want to do exactly? You can't, in Javascript, swap variables in this way!

Answer (score 0):

Trying in browser:

```
[a,b] = [b,a]
```

Result:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

In other words: this isn't allowed in JavaScript.

CoffeeScript (which compiles to JavaScript) does, however.

Comment: @Sethunath look at the browser console, you can see the logged error there

Comment: I've learned something new today: what you are doing is going to be implemented in JavaScript version 1.7, but for obvious reasons, it may take very long time before you can expect it to work everywhere.