# Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I just wondering why I get the error when I do the following:

```
function something(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
something('id') = 'hello';
```

But I can do this without error:

```
document.getElementById('id').value = 'hello';
```

They are suppose just the same thing, right?

Of course, assume there is an input element with id, named 'id'.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a valid left-hand-side expression in JavaScript grammar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709866/whats-a-valid-left-hand-side-expression-in-javascript-grammar)

Answer (score 0):

Well in the first example you try to assign something to the result of a function, while in the second example you assign something to a property of an object.

Maybe the misunderstanding results from the fact that the return value of the function is just the "contents" of the property (i.e. a string) and not a reference to it.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to call the function with the value and do the assigning there:

```
function something(id, v){
    document.getElementById(id).value = v;
}
something('id', 'hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're first approach is about retrieval data.
2. Whereas the second part is about assigning the data.  Here *You're are assigning value to something `function` variable.*

May you need to change like below

```
function something(id, val){
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

Then call it like

```
something('id', 'hello');
```