# JavaScript LHS and RHS Lookup

Tags: javascript, lookup

I was reading the Scopes and Closure of You don't know JS book by Kyle Simpson, specifically this topic **Compiler Speak**.

There they mention the **LHS and RHS lookup**. I am failed to understand these two terms, can anyone help me to realize them?

Comment: please have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709866/whats-a-valid-left-hand-side-expression-in-javascript-grammar

Comment: Please quote the relevant portions of the book.

Comment: The most frequent use of the term is about style, the popular `x==1`, and the also valid `1==x`.

Answer (score 16):

LHS look-up is done when a variable appears on the left-hand side of an assignment operation, and an RHS look-up is done when a variable appears on the right-hand side of an assignment operation.

I think of it as follows : 
lhs lookup is a container lookup 
rhs lookup is a value lookup

Answer (score 16):

Don't think of it as a left hand side or right hand side assignment, think of it as storing the value into memory and retrieving it later.

For example when you type `b` in the chrome developer console, it starts the `RHS` lookup (retrieve the value of `b`) and if the value is not found, it throws `ReferenceError`.

In contrast when you type the `b = 2` in chrome developer console, it starts `LHS` lookup, and if b is not found in the nested scope the JS compiler declares it in the global scope (depending on whether you are running code in `strict mode` or not).

For example take following code into consideration

```html
function foo(a) {
    console.log( a + b)
}

foo( 2 );
```

When the JS compiler executes the code it first looks for the function `foo` and whether it is declared in the current scope (Hosting Environment Here) which is called RHS lookup. Now in the scope of foo the argument will be 2 and as we declared function `foo(a)` when we wrote `foo( 2 )` we are implicitly assigning the value `2` to `a` or `a = 2`, which is called `LHS` lookup (assigning value `2` to `a`), now fast-forward the compiler will come to line `console.log( a + b)` again it will look for value `a` and `b` (again `RHS` lookup) and if the values are found it will assign it to `console.log` argument (if you assume that `console.log` is defined as `console.log(arg1)` in the hosting environment then `arg1 = value of a+b` (which is again `LHS` lookup).

In short:

• when the engine retrieves the value of a variable `console.log(b)`, it gets the value from the memory location of `b`. This is a `RHS` lookup

• when the engine assigns the value to the variable `b = 2`, it looks for the value of `b` in the scope – if found, it sets the value `2` in the memory location of `b`, if not, it look in the upper level scope. This is a `LHS` lookup.

Comment: There is also an ```RHS``` look-up for the console object. Then a property resolution occurs to see if it has a method called log.

Answer (score 9):

Simple example from the same book you have mentioned

```
function foo(a) {
console.log( a ); // 2
}
foo( 2 );
```

**LHS** : When you pass a value(2) to the foo method , compiler will assign to the parameter as
**a = 2**  , is called LHS Lookup. It will simply find a container variable to assign the value.

**RHS** :In order to execute console.log to print **a**, need an RHS reference for the value of a. It's called RHS Lookup

**Another Example**

```
function foo(a) {
var b = a;
return a + b;
}
var c = foo( 2 );
```

**3 LHS** from the above example -**

1. **c =** (container to hold the return of foo method)
2. **a = 2** (When you pass value 2 to the method, compiler will assign a = 2)
3. **b =**

**4 RHS from the above code snippet**

1. **foo(2)** - need a reference of a to get the value
2. **= a** - to get the value of b , need a reference of a
3. **a** - to get the value of a , need a reference of a
4. **b** - to get the value of b , need a reference of b

---

Edit:

Comment: I like this answer

Answer (score 5):

LHS - Look for an identifier for assigning purposes or for assigning a value to it.

```
let foo;

// It's looking for foo identifier in global scope and assign value
// So it's an LHS 
foo = 1; 

// It's also LHS as it assigning new value
foo = 2;
```

Now, RHS - it means when you're looking for an identifier to use it (not to assign value)

```
function foo() {
    alert(2);
}

// this look for an identifier called foo and 
// in global scope it's a function decoration 
// and execute it
foo();
```

Answer (score 4):

I think of it as follows : 
lhs lookup is a container lookup 
rhs lookup is a value lookup

I like Kyle Simpson's approach a lot but this particular nutshell explanation brought home the point loud and clear to me.

There's always  a trade between "just tell what I need to know, nothing more" and drilling down to understand better at a deep level.

Sometimes that deep understanding can help you keep out of trouble, how to debug, write test code, optimize and refactor.

I am currently reading and watching a lot of Kyle's writing and online teaching, he does have knack for explaining things well. A lot of instructors lose people along the way either by going too fast because the have expertise and it's hard for them to slow down - on the other hand if you get too basic the talk gets uninteresting and you just tune out.

Answer (score 2):

Or short:

RHS  - for read lookup

LHS - for write lookup